# Cannot login onto sftp using Bizzflow.net sftp extractor

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I cannot sucessfully log in onto our SFTP server using ex-sftp, which is part of Bizzflow.net. When I try to use credetials in any SFTP client, it works, but using Bizzflow.net extractor ends with `incorrect name or password` error message.

Answer (score 1):

the issue is when username uses some non alphabetical characters. Typically, when SFTP is hosted on Windows server and login uses `domain\username` format, this issue occurs. The reason is the ex-sftp does not encode username correctly. Best solution would be to use local username without `domain\` prefix. Also you can submit bug to ex-sftp on https://gitlab.com/bizzflow-extractors/ex-sft